# Microsoft Graph API Initials attribute

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Hey I would like to retrieve the Initials of a user in the graph explorer. I synchronized thies field with AD Connect zu Azure AD but in the documentation i dont see any property like that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

I know the attribute is on Azure AD but how can i retrieve it with the Graph API?

Thanks & best regards

Answer (score 0):

In the AAD, it doesn't define this property `Initials`, it is a user's attribute in AD not in AAD.

In AD, you could use powershell to get a user's Initials by this:

```
Get-ADUser "YourUser" -Properties Initials
```

In MS graph exploerer, I tried `Get Https://https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=Initials` for all the user (included synced users from AD), and then the return value is null for all the user.

[image]

The return:

[image]

Comment: I know the field is being synchronized to Azure somehow (i can see all attributes on AD Connect being synced). This documentation sais its being used for Exchange Online or Sharepoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized So is there no way to access thies field with Graph API or Powershell?

Comment: @Lephas, in your  mentioned [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized#exchange-online), the `Initials ` cannot be synchronized for the users of  the exchange online and sharepoint.

Comment: I checked the AAD Connect settings again, it sais Initials are getting synced - when I perform a Metaverse Search i can find the Initials as well. I just dont know how to access those Initials on Azure AD (Powershell or Graph or any other way..)

Comment: @Lephas, have you tried `Get  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userid}?$select=Initials`?